# Regex to Match Symbols: !$%^&*()_+|~-=`{}[]:";'<>?,./

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to create a Regex test in JavaScript that will test a string to contain any of these characters:

```
!$%^&*()_+|~-=`{}[]:";'<>?,./
```

**More Info If You're Interested :)**

It's for a pretty cool password change application I'm working on. In case you're interested here's the rest of the code.

I have a table that lists password requirements and as end-users types the new password, it will test an array of Regexes and place a checkmark in the corresponding table row if it... checks out :) I just need to add this one in place of the 4th item in the `validation` array.

```
var validate = function(password){
    valid = true;

    var validation = [
        RegExp(/[a-z]/).test(password), RegExp(/[A-Z]/).test(password), RegExp(/\d/).test(password), 
        RegExp(/\W|_/).test(password), !RegExp(/\s/).test(password), !RegExp("12345678").test(password), 
        !RegExp($('#txtUsername').val()).test(password), !RegExp("cisco").test(password), 
        !RegExp(/([a-z]|[0-9])\1\1\1/).test(password), (password.length > 7)
    ]

    $.each(validation, function(i){
        if(this)
            $('.form table tr').eq(i+1).attr('class', 'check');
        else{
            $('.form table tr').eq(i+1).attr('class', '');
            valid = false
        }
    });

    return(valid);

}
```

**Yes, there's also corresponding server-side validation!**

Comment: It's quite funny that the answer to your question lies in the title with the exception of escaping special characters and enclosing forward slashes.

Comment: Why not use `.addClass("check")` and `.removeClass("check")`?  And seeing `if (someBoolean == true)` in code always makes me cringe.  Just do `if (someBoolean)`.  Or, better yet, just do `$(".form table tr").eq(i+1).toggleClass("check", !!this); valid = valid && !!this;`.

Comment: +1 @gill3 thx for the code review- great feedback indeed. I've def used those short-hand methods in the past.

Comment: @gilly3, it appears to work great in FF but !IE8.  love this short-hand.  I'm trying to figure out what IE8 is doing differently.

Answer (score 204, accepted):

The regular expression for this is really simple.  Just use a character class.  The hyphen is a special character in character classes, so it needs to be first:

```
/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]/
```

You also need to escape the other regular expression metacharacters.

**Edit:**
The hyphen is special because it can be used to represent a range of characters.  This same character class can be simplified with ranges to this:

```
/[$-/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]]/
```

There are three ranges.  '$' to '/', ':' to '?', and '{' to '~'.  the last string of characters can't be represented more simply with a range: !"^_`[].

Use an [ACSII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to find ranges for character classes.

Comment: Why is not mentioned quantifiers \Q and \E for escaping the sequence of characters?

Comment: Before finding this solution I was going down the character class exclusion route: match everything BUT alpha, digits, white space, etc.

Comment: Is it common knowledge that hyphens have to come first? I've read dozens of SO answers and regex cheat sheets this is the first I've heard of it. Your answer saved me a lot of drama. Thanks!

Comment: @SerG `\Q` and `\E` don't work in the JS _RegExp_ engine :( `/^\Q.\E$/.test('Q+E'); // true`

Comment: It seems that this answer fail to match backslash.

Comment: @q4w56 backslash isn't in the set of characters specified in the original question, so not matching backslash is correct.  :)

Comment: This answer also doesn't match #, at least in php & JS.

Comment: ```/[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}[\]:";'<>?,./\\]/```  this expression worked for me with backslash.

Comment: Doesn't match `@`

Comment: The hyphen can go both in the beginning or the end

Answer (score 20):

## Answer

```
/[\W\S_]/
```

## Explanation

This creates a character class removing the word characters, space characters, and adding back the underscore character (as underscore is a "word" character).  All that is left is the special characters. Capital letters represent the negation of their lowercase counterparts.

`\W` will select all non "word" characters equivalent to `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`
`\S` will select all non "whitespace" characters equivalent to `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`
`_` will select "_" because we negate it when using the `\W` and need to add it back in

Comment: MikeSchem, you just took me through a time machine.

Comment: yea, I noticed it. was old, but I felt the simplest answer wasn't posted.

Comment: how is this different from the answer below that fails on underscore?

Comment: @MikeSchem You travelled ahead of time. Awesomely simple and sweet

Comment: Tried this on regex101.com.  As written with square brackets this captures everything.  It works without square brackets if some symbols are properly escaped (eg. _ , + , - , @, etc).

Answer (score 15):

The most simple and shortest way to accomplish this:

```
/[^\p{L}\d\s@#]/u
```

### Explanation

`[^...]`  Match a single character not present in the list below

- `\p{L}` => matches any kind of letter from any language
- `\d` => matches a digit zero through nine
- `\s` => matches any kind of invisible character
- `@#`  => `@` and `#` characters

Don't forget to pass the `u` (unicode) flag.

Comment: wouldn't you need a ^ to indicate not?

Comment: @Webber No. They're in capital and this makes the statement negative. `^` is needed when we use `\w` and `\s` in small letters.

Comment: Doesn't this interpret it so that either outside `w` or outside `s`, and since those two don't really intersect it just lets through all of the characters? (Thus not filtering anything.)

Comment: @Zael You're right, the regular expression as stated (`/[\W\S]/`) does let everything through. A more accurate representation of what I believe Amir was getting at would be `[^\w\s]`. In the former, the regular expression is saying "match anything that is not alphanumeric **OR** that is not whitespace", which as you mentioned let's everything through since alphanumeric characters are not whitespace and vice versa. The latter says "match anything that is not alphanumeric **AND** that is not whitespace". Of course, exceptions apply in that accented characters (like `À`) are matched by `[^\w\s]`.

Comment: this doesn't include the _ char

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox, I get "SyntaxError: invalid identity escape in regular expression" . Works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Doesn't work in a quick test at https://regex101.com/.  The php>=7.3 doesn't catch the `#` or `@` and the Python version catches all the letters but also not`#` or `@`

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve this is the negative set [^\w\s]. This essentially catches:

- Anything that is not an alphanumeric character (letters and numbers)
- Anything that is not a space, tab, or line break (collectively referred to as whitespace)

For some reason [\W\S] does not work the same way, it doesn't do any filtering. A comment by Zael on one of the answers provides something of an explanation.

Comment: No, the underscore is missing and all characters out of the ascii range and most of the control characters in the ascii range would match this class. `/[^\w\s]/.test('é') # true`, `/[^\w\s]/.test('_') # false`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// The string must contain at least one special character, escaping reserved RegEx characters to avoid conflict
  const hasSpecial = password => {
    const specialReg = new RegExp(
      '^(?=.*[!@#$%^&*"\\[\\]\\{\\}<>/\\(\\)=\\\\\\-_´+`~\\:;,\\.€\\|])',
    );
    return specialReg.test(password);
  };
```

Comment: Don't use the `RegExp` constructor when you can just use a regex literal. Much less escaping work (most of which are unnecessary anyway), and it's more efficient as well.

Comment: Why use a complicated lookahead when you can just match the character directly?

Comment: Can you give an example @Bergi? I don't understand what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

to build upon @jeff-hillman answer, this is the complete version

```
/[\\@#$-/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]]/
```

Tests

```
function noSpecialChars(str) {
  const match = str.match(/[\\@#$-/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]]/)
  if (!match) return
  
  throw new Error("got unsupported characters: " + match[0])
}

// prettier-ignore
const symbols = ["!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "-", "_", "+", "=", ".", ":", ";", "|","~","`","{","}","[","]","\"","'","<",">","?","/", "\\"]

symbols.forEach((s) => {
  it(`validates no symbol ${s}`, async () => {
    expect(() => {
      noSpecialChars(s)
    }).toThrow();
  })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

How about `(?=\W_)(?=\S).`? It checks that the character matched by the `.` is not a word character (however `_` is allowed) and that it's not whitespace.

Note: as @Casimir et Hippolyte pointed out in another comment, this will also match characters like é and such. If you don't expect such characters then this is a working solution.