# Regex to Match: !$%^&*()_+|~-=`{}[]:";'<>?,./

Tags: java, android, regex

I know this a duplicate of a question with almost the identical name, however, I can't get it to work in Android what so ever!

I am trying this: Regex to Match Symbols:

```
public Pattern bsymbols = Pattern.compile("[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\\[\\]:\\";'<>?,.\/]");
```

However, this isn't working. Does anyone know the correct method of applying this pattern?

P.S. Complete noob at Regex. :D

From here originally - [Regex to Match Symbols: !$%^&*()_+|~-=`{}[]:";'<>?,./](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359566/regex-to-match-symbols)

Error Message: `Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)`

UPDATE: Added extra backslashes...fixed a lot of em, now gets error from `;` onwards. Using Eclipse.

Comment: Is it the problem with backslashes again? (when backslash is a string literal escape in your programming language, two backslashes should be used to get *one* backslash to the regexp engine)

Comment: @RohitJain it's continuously underlined in Eclipse indicating an error.

Comment: @Asryael.. That error message would be more than helpful here.

Comment: Use \\ if you want to specify a \ if it is not a part of an escape sequence according to the language.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA has a nice support for regexps (syntax highlighting + instant match against user input).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about that?

```
Pattern.compile("[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\\[\\]:\";'<>?,.\\\\/]");
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `(` and `)` in a character class.

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is the "

```
public Pattern bsymbols = Pattern.compile("[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.\/]");
                                                                  ^
```

it is ending your string, so you should escape it. Also you need to remove the backslash before the slash, it is no special character.

```
public Pattern bsymbols = Pattern.compile("[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\\[\\]:\";'<>?,./]");
```

OK, once more, you wanted to match the backslash, not to escape the slash, then we end up here:

```
public Pattern bsymbols = Pattern.compile("[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\\[\\]:\";'<>?,.\\\\/]");
```

now it is the same answer, than jdb's, so +1 to him for being quicker.

Comment: Also need to double escape `\[` and `\]`.

Comment: @stema what's the need of escaping `;` ?

Comment: Still not getting any lovin' after copy-pasting your expression. - `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

Comment: you need to esape '()' '.' '?' '+' '*' '|' '{}' '[]' as they are all special characters in regexp, and you have to use double backslashes in java to escape a character

Comment: @AdamL.Mónos every special character except `[`, \ and `]` is the character itself inside character class.

Comment: @Asryael, I updated my expression. I am not sure about the escaping, I think the regex special characters need 2 backslash and the string special characters only one.

Comment: @Asryael, so I started up eclipse and tested the expression and fixed it once more, you need also to remove the escaping from the slash. It is no special character in Java regex and Java strings claims an "invalid escape sequence"

Answer (score 1):

In a character class, only `[` and `]` have special meaning, so you need to escape them. Plus in Java, you need to escape with an extra backslash. That's the problem specifically with Java. So, you need to use `\\[` and `\\]`. And yes, you need to escape `"` with single backslash, in a string literal.

Apart from that, a hyphen when used somewhere in the middle, has also a special meaning. If you want to match a `hyphen`, you need to use it at the ends.

Rest of the characters, don't need to be escaped. They are just ordinary characters.

So, your pattern should be like this: -

```
Pattern bsymbols = Pattern.compile("[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\\[\\]:\";'<>?,./]");
```

And if you want to match `backslash (\)` also, then use this: -

```
Pattern bsymbols = Pattern.compile("[-!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\\[\\]:\";'<>?,.\\\\/]");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works for the characters listed, however you are missing the backslash character if I am correct.

Comment: \ should be escaped inside character class also.

Comment: @Asryael.. Yeah added that. I thought you were using it for escaping `/` . But to match a *backslash*, you need to use four backslashes   . Two for Regex, and two for Java.