# Regex to validate a password

Tags: javascript, html, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Password validation regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068843/password-validation-regex)

between 8 and 16 characters, with at least 1 character from each of the 3 character classes -alphabetic upper and lower case, numeric, symbols.

I have this code, but it doesn't work, when I write more than 16 characters, gives it as valid, but it should not; the it should to work ok with 3 character classes, but it works with 4, where's my mistake??

http://jsbin.com/ugesow/1/edit

```
<label for="pass">Enter Pass: </label>
<input type="text" id="pass" onkeyup="validate()">
```

Script

```
function validate() {
    valor = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    if (!(/(?=.{8,16})(?=.*?[^\w\s])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z]).*?[a-z].*/.test(valor))) {

        document.getElementById('pass').style.backgroundColor = "red";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('pass').style.backgroundColor = "#adff2f";
    }
}
```

Comment: are you interested in making this specific regex working? elsewhere you can divide your problem in smaller pieces, like checking length, etc.

Comment: Check it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370015/regular-expression-for-password-validation

Comment: It would ideal if you provide a list of examples of what should be valid and what not.

Comment: @vault is not the same

Comment: @Kakitori: It's very similar.

Comment: @Kakitori lol, it's almost the same

Comment: What's your reason for limiting the length of the password to 16 characters? If you're hashing (and salting, as you should be) your passwords, it won't make it take any more space in the database. The only thing you might be worried about is bandwidth, but validating it after you've received it does not help that. I know that I personally have some passwords that are over 32 characters long.

Comment: my regex is between 8 and 16 characters

Comment: ...then change `{8,}` to `{8,16}`...

Comment: it's already changed, but it doesn't work http://jsbin.com/ugesow/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not a panacea. It's not too hard to do it, mixing with regular code:

```
function validatePassword(password) {
    // First, check the length.
    // Please see my comment on the question about maximum password lengths.
    if(password.length < 8 || password.length > 16) return false;
    // Next, check for alphabetic characters.
    if(!/[A-Z]/i.match(password)) return false;
    // Next, check for numbers.
    if(!/\d/.match(password)) return false;
    // Next, check for anything besides those.
    if(!/[^A-Z\d]/i.match(password)) return false;
    // If we're here, it's valid.
    return true;
}
```

However, I'd look into something like [zxcvbn](https://github.com/lowe/zxcvbn), a password checker, which I think is a better password quality checker, checking things like common dictionary words after un-[13375p3/-\k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet)ification and [dealing with entropy decently](http://xkcd.com/936/). It is used, among others, by Dropbox. [Try it here.](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/209/zxcvbn/test/index.html)

Comment: that's how i would solve this :D

Answer (score 0):

You need to anchor the match to the beginning of the string, and anchor the first lookahead to the end:

```
^(?=.{8,16}$)
```

Also, the last lookahead needs to be split in two:

```
(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])
```

Comment: ^(?=.{8,16}$) it's already chagend, but it doesn't work  http://jsbin.com/ugesow/1/edit

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you just test for the three character sets with regular expressions:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]+
```

Then count the length of the string to validate the length.

Comment: your regex accepts almost every non symbol character, this is not what he asked

Comment: I used the notation found in "the Dragon Book" as I had thought that was the standard. I reckoned it would be easy enough to translate it to the JavaScript syntax. :\

Comment: I haven't read it, but I would expect a book on compilers to talk about theory-pure regular expressions, not the regexes we use for string manipulations.  Big, *big* difference.

Answer (score -3):

What about this range:

```
/[A-Za-z0-9$-/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]]/
```

So you can check first

```
/[A-Za-z]+/
```

then

```
/\d+/
```

and finally

```
/[$-/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]]+/
```

If it passes you can check the length.

You can see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359566/regex-to-match-symbols) to see why the symbols work.

Comment: He can use these to check for the things he need, it's not the actual regex.

Comment: you seem the only one to think that

Comment: Really? He can check for symbols, letters and numbers. So if he do something like:  /[A-Za-z]+/ then /\d+/ and finally /[$-/:-?{-~!"^_`\[\]+] he can do what he wants... there is a better way, but is valid.

Comment: This does *not* do what the OP was asking for. A single character password would pass, which is *incorrect* by the requirement.