# I want to make sure the input is a String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, servlets

In a web project, I am creating a Student Registration Program.

I have a .jsp file for students to register in order to add/drop etc.

How should I modify my javascript code to check to make sure only String is allowed for userName input?

Here is a piece of my .jsp file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>New User Registration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="get" action="RegServlet">
        <h1>Register!</h1>
            Fill out information below:<p>                

            Username:
            <input type="text" name="userName" value =""><p>
<input type="submit" value="Finish!"><p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var var1 = "userName";
            if(var1 == (""))
                document.write("<bSystem doesn't like an empty string.....Try Again!!!</b>");
            else if(var1 == ("notmatch"))
                document.write("<b>Inappropriate input!!!.....Try Again!!!</b>");
```

And one more thing:

I keep getting an HTTP Status 404 Error when I click "Finish!". It should be leading me to the login.jsp file that is indicated in my RegServlet.java file because form method="get" action="RegServlet" should do that for me. But it seems like it's telling me it cannot find the "/Registrar/RegServlet" path. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a piece of my RegServlet code:

```
 public void doStuff(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, SQLException {
    //see if search parameter is present        
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String passWord = request.getParameter("passWord");
    String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String age = request.getParameter("age");
    char sex = request.getParameter("sex").charAt(0);
    String email = request.getParameter("email");

    if(!userName.isEmpty()&&!passWord.isEmpty()&&!lastName.isEmpty()&&!firstName.isEmpty()&&!age.isEmpty()&& sex!='F' || sex!='M' &&!email.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            SaveToDB.createConnection();
            toDB.insertNewUser(userName, passWord, lastName, firstName, age, sex, email);
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
        } catch(SQLException sqlEx) {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    } else {
        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only thing you can get as the value of an input is a string. There's nothing to check.

Comment: Oh great! Thanks. What about in the sex field? Can the user enter a numeric value instead of char 'M' or 'F'?

Comment: The user can enterwhatever he want in an input field of type text. Bu it will always be a string. This string might contain numeric characters, but it will always be a string.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 5):

A word of warning: For your program all client side validation is in vain: you can never trust it, you always have to do server side validation also.  But for a user of your program client side validation is a convenience: faster feedback.

Look into HTML5 forms: you can do validation with html only now:

```
  <input type="text" name="userName"  pattern="^[A-Za-z ]+$" >
```

see

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/#toc-validation

If you want to do clientside validation in javascript you have to learn about
the "onsubmit" event first.

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/07/web-form-validation-best-practices-and-tutorials/ gives a good overview of all the techniques.

Answer (score 1):

Apply a Regex for the input string and check for special characters.

here is a sample of Special characters Regex:
[Regex to Match Symbols: !$%^&*()_+|~-=`{}[]:";'<>?,./](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359566/regex-to-match-symbols)

Answer (score 0):

Give the correct `action` path in `<form method="get" action="RegServlet">` to avoid 404 error.
Try `<form method="get" action="/RegServlet">`

Comment: Thanks javapirate, I just tried that and it gave me a "Oops! This link appears to be broken." error page.

Comment: did you try `action="/Registrar/RegServlet"` or `action="Registrar/RegServlet"`

Comment: Just did but no luck. Thanks though!