# Microsoft C++ exception: std::regex_error at memory location

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, c++11

I wrote the following code for parsing command line arguments, using Visual C++ 2012.
These command-line parameters have traditional GNU style (--option).

```
void parseCmdLines(int argc, wchar_t* argv[]) {
  for (auto i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
    std::wstring arg(argv[i]);
    // I hope it can match the L"--config=../etc/my.conf"
    std::wregex regex(L"--config=(+*)");
    std::wsmatch match;
    std::regex_match(arg, match, regex);

    // TODO: ...
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run this program, I met an exception. The description of the exception is as follows:

```
Microsoft C++ exception: std::regex_error at memory location 0x23F090.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your testcase? A `main`?

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359566/regex-to-match-symbols

Answer (score 5):

It's likely that your problem is with `+*`.

`+` means one or more of what appears before it and `*` means zero or more of what appears before it (since there is a `(` before the `+`, it shouldn't work, since this merely means the start of a group, and for the `+` before the `*`, you can't really say "zero or more of one or more").

Did you maybe mean `.*` (i.e. zero or more of anything) or `.+` (i.e. one or more of anything)?

Comment: Thank you for helping me solve this problem. I really remiss. :)

Comment: i solved it using "\\" slash trick const std::regex reg_off_p("\\+[0-9A-F]{2}");