# std::regex throws Microsoft C++ exception: std::regex_error at memory location on runtime

Tags: regex, c++11

In the last two hours I've tried to understand why the line of code from below

```
std::regex matchPattern{R"(?<=\@)(.*?)(?=\=)"};
```

throws **Microsoft C++ exception: std::regex_error at memory location ....**

I've tested the regular expresion with online tools and notepad++ and everything works just fine. When I'm trying to use it in my c++ app  I get the runtime error from above on initialization. 
I am using c++14

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I tried this and didn't get any error. It might be possible to replicate the error if a [mcve] is posted.

Comment: Does it work with `std::regex matchPattern("^[^@[]*");`? Note you do not need to escape `[` inside a character class.

Comment: Sorry guys. By mistake I've added the wrong regex ... (i guess I am a little bit tired :) ). I've updated the regex in the initial question

Comment: C++ std::regex does not support lookbehind. Probably you want `R"(@([^=]+))"` and grab the Group 1 value. Please share your code. See [**this C++ demo**](https://ideone.com/Btbu0H).

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359566/regex-to-match-symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++14 `std::regex` (any of its flavors) does not support lookbehind construct.

You may use `R"(@([^=]+))"` and grab the Group 1 value. Note that `R"(` and `)"` are the raw string literal boundaries, and the `@([^=]+)` is the real string pattern that matches `@` and then matches and captures 1+ chars other than `=` into Group 1.

See [**this C++ demo**](https://ideone.com/Btbu0H):

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::regex matchPattern(R"(@([^=]+))");
    std::string s("@test=boundary");
    std::smatch matches;
    if (std::regex_search(s, matches, matchPattern)) {
        std::cout<<matches.str(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
test
```

Comment: i solved it using "\\" slash trick const std::regex reg_off_p("\\+[0-9A-F]{2}");