# Regular Expression to check Special characters except hypen and forwardslash

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to know regex code to check whether it contains Special characters other than hypen and forwardslash in javascript

```
function containsSpecialCharacters(str){
    var regex = /[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g;
        return regex.test(str);
  }


var result = containsSpecialCharacters("sample"); // false
var result = containsSpecialCharacters("sample-test"); // false
var result = containsSpecialCharacters("sample++"); // true
var result = containsSpecialCharacters("/sample/test"); // false
```

Comment: What do tags `jquery`, `html` and `css` have to do with anything?

Comment: Backslash ot forward slash?

Comment: According to your introduction, the final example should resolve true, not false.

Comment: Just remove them from character class.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal regex to search for all ASCII special characters, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359566/regex-to-match-symbols), and then just remove the hypen and backslash:

```
/[!$%^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]:";'<>?,.]/
```

If you want to avoid any other special character, you just have to remove it from the regex.

You can test this regex here: https://regex101.com/r/gxYiGp/2

Answer (score 0):

If you need to support only English characters, it would be far easier to list the exceptions than those you wish to match:

```
/[^\w\s\\\-]/.test(myString);
```

As noted, though, this will fail if you need to support international characters.

Answer (score 0):

you can just **negate** it so it looks shorter, like this :

```
[^\s\w-]
```

Comment: This will produce “invalid range”. `_` is already included in `\w`