# Can someone please fix it so that the function can detect whether the input has at least one symbol in it?

Tags: python, list, function, parsing, special-characters

```
import os
import time

def strong(password, verifier):
  symbols = "! # $ % & ( ) * + , - . / : ; = ? @ [ ] ^ _ ` { | } ~"
  password = str(password)
  if len(password) > 8:
    if len(password) < 15:
        for i in symbols:
          if password.find(symbols) is True:
```

I want to see if I can fix this part because I am not sure how I can use this function to find a special character in the password.

```
            if password.isalnum():
              verifier = 1
              return 'good password', verifier
            elif password.isalpha():
              return 'Your password is only letters'
            elif password.isnumeric():
              return 'Your password is only numbers'
          else:
            return 'no symbols'
    else:
      return 'Too big'
  else:
    return 'Too small'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to Match Symbols: !$%^&\*()\_+|~-=\`{}\[\]:";'<>?,./](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359566/regex-to-match-symbols)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a string contains an element from a list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531482/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-an-element-from-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this (and make debugging easier) by just `return`ing after each failed check instead of having all the deeply nested `if/else`.  Since in the "good password" case you're returning a "verifier" as well as the "good password" message, I'm figuring you probably want to return a false value for the "bad password" cases as well:

```
def is_strong(password):
    symbols = set("!#$%&()*+,-./:;=?@[]^_`{|}~")
    if len(password) < 9:
        return "Too small", False
    if len(password) > 14:
        return "Too big", False
    if not any(c in symbols for c in password):
        return "No symbols", False
    if password.isalpha():
        return "Your password is only letters", False
    if password.isnumeric():
        return "your password is only numbers", False
    return "Good password", True
```

Once the function is simplified down, we can see that the `isalpha` and `isnumeric` checks won't actually do anything, because we've already established that the password contains non-alphanumeric symbols!  Instead I think you want to do:

```
def is_strong(password):
    symbols = set("!#$%&()*+,-./:;=?@[]^_`{|}~")
    if len(password) < 9:
        return "Too small", False
    if len(password) > 14:
        return "Too big", False
    if not any(c in symbols for c in password):
        return "No symbols", False
    if not any(c.isalpha() for c in password):
        return "No letters", False
    if not any(c.isdigit() for c in password):
        return "No numbers", False
    return "Good password", True
```

We can test the function like this:

```
strong, password = False, ""
while not strong:
    password = input("Set password: ")
    msg, strong = is_strong(password)
    print(msg)
```

```
Set password: bob
Too small
Set password: bobledeboingerberoo
Too big
Set password: bobbington
No symbols
Set password: bobbington!
No numbers
Set password: bobbington3!
Good password
```

Comment: Thanks! This is nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `any()` along with a generator comprehension to check this:

```
if any(ch in password for ch in symbols):
```

I will point out that the symbols list also contains spaces, so you may want to take those out if you don't want a space to qualify as a symbol.

Comment: symbols.split() could be used to remove the spaces

Answer (score 0):

Make your list of special characters a set and you'll be able to use the `isdisjoint` function to check that there are no symbols in the password:

```
if {*"!#$%&()*+,-./:;=?@[]^_`{|}~"}.isdisjoint(password):
    print("Password has no symbols")
else:
    print("Password contains at least one symbol")
```